# Multiply numbers represented as arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, multiplication

I have to write a function that multiplies two numbers represented by two int arrays (so I can't use ArrayLists or something).

Each digit of a number is represented by an `int` between 0 and 9 in the array, no element should be greater than that.

The first element of the array represents the last digit of the number and so on, therefore the number `1234` would be `{4,3,2,1}` as an array in this function.

I thought multiplying those arrays that way would be similar to long multiplication, so I tried to implement it in a similar way: You multiply every digit of the first array with every digit of the second one and store the rest if the result is equal or greater to 10 and then add it to the next digit. However, I seem to have done something wrong in the code (maybe the calculation of the rest??) because the result of my function is not correct: I tested it with 190 times 86 (represented by the arrays `{0,9,1}` and `{6,8}`) and get `15342` (`{2,4,3,5,1}`) instead of the actual result `16340` (which would be `{0,4,3,6,1}`).

Can somebody here help me out with this please? This is my code:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
public class MultiplyArrays {

 static int[ ] times(int[ ] a, int[ ] b) {
   int[] arr = new int[a.length + b.length - 1];//arr should be the result of a*b. The result shouldn't be shorter than that
   int tmp = 0;//stores the rest of two-digit numbers
   for(int i = b.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
     for(int j = 0; j < a.length; j++){//should multiply all digits of a with the current index of b
       arr[i + j] = (arr[i + j] + (b[i] * a[j] + tmp)) % 10;//sets the value of the (i+j)th index in arr to the multiplication of two numbers from a and b adding the rest tmp.
       if((arr[i + j] + b[i] * a[j] + tmp) < 10){//if this number is less than 10, there is no rest
         tmp = 0;
       }
       else{//otherwise, the rest should be the second digit
         tmp = (((arr[i + j] + (b[i] * a[j] + tmp))) - ((arr[i + j] + (b[i] * a[j] + tmp)) % 10)) / 10;//something in the formula for the rest is wrong, I guess
       }
     }
   }
   if(tmp != 0){//if the last number of the array containing the result is calculated and there still is a rest, a new array with one more digit is created
     int[] arr2 = new int[arr.length + 1];
     for(int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){//the new array copies all numbers from the old array
       arr2[i] = arr[i];
       arr2[arr2.length - 1] = tmp;//the last space is the rest now
     }
     return arr2;
   }
   else{//if there is no rest after calculating the last number of arr, a new array isn't needed
     return arr;
   }
 }
    public static void main(String[] args) {//test the function with 190 * 86
        int[] a = {0,9,1};
        int[] b = {6,8};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(times(a,b)));
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this a homework question? I'd convert it into a string, reverse it, convert to int, multiply both, then re-convert back. A better way could be to sum each number, increasing by `10**n` every number (and looping through array backwards) then multiplying the resulting two integers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this comes from the fact that your indices in the for-loops of the times()-method are incrementing AND decrementing.
The i is going down and the j is going up. 
Also, in the second for loop, you should only increment to 'a.length - 1', not to 'a.length'.

Answer (score 0):

Arbitrary precision multiplication is more complex than it seems, and contains corner cases (like one and zero). Fortunately, Java has an arbitrary precision type; [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html). In order to use it here, you would need to create two additional methods; one for converting an `int[]` to a `BigInteger`, and the second the convert a `BigInteger` to an `int[]`.

The first can be done with a single loop adding each digit at index `i` (multiplied by 10<sup>i</sup>) to a running total. Like,

```
private static BigInteger fromArray(int[] arr) {
    BigInteger bi = BigInteger.ZERO;
    for (int i = 0, pow = 1; i < arr.length; pow *= 10, i++) {
        bi = bi.add(BigInteger.valueOf(arr[i] * pow));
    }
    return bi;
}
```

And the second can be done a number of ways, but the easiest is simply to convert the `BigInteger` to a `String` to get the `length()` - once you've done that, you know the length of the output array - and can populate the digits in it. Like,

```
private static int[] toArray(BigInteger bi) {
    String s = bi.toString();
    int len = s.length();
    int[] r = new int[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        r[i] = s.charAt(len - i - 1) - '0';
    }
    return r;
}
```

Finally, call those two methods and let `BigInteger` perform the multiplication. Like,

```
static int[] times(int[] a, int[] b) {
    BigInteger ba = fromArray(a), bb = fromArray(b);
    return toArray(ba.multiply(bb));
}
```

Running your original `main` with those changes outputs (as expected)

```
[0, 4, 3, 6, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your thought would work with addition, but on multiplication you multiply each digit of one with the whole number of the other and step one digit to the left (*10) each time you change the multiplication digit of the first number.

So you might brought something into confusion.

I just solved it in a more structured way, running the debugger will hopefully explain the process. In the solutions you can remove the trailing / leading zero by checking the digit if 0 and replace the array with one of length - 1.

The solutions are:

- With conditions mentioned (numbers in reverse order):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {3,2,1};
        int[] b = {9,8};

        System.out.println("Result is: " + Arrays.toString(calculate(a, b)));
    }

    private static int[] calculate(int[] a, int[] b) {
        // final result will be never longer than sum of number lengths + 1
        int[] finalResult = new int[a.length + b.length + 1];

        int position = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            int[] tempResult = multiplyWithOther(a[i], b);
            addToFinalResult(finalResult, tempResult, position);
            position++;
        }
        return finalResult;
    }

    private static int[] multiplyWithOther(int number, int[] otherArray) {
        // The number cannot be more digits than otherArray.length + 1, so create a temp array with size +1
        int[] temp = new int[otherArray.length + 1];
        // Iterate through the seconds array and multiply with current number from first
        int remainder = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < otherArray.length; i++) {
            int result = number * otherArray[i];
            result += remainder;
            remainder = result / 10;
            temp[i] = result % 10;
        }
        // Add remainder (even if 0) to start
        temp[temp.length - 1] = remainder;
        return temp;
    }

    private static void addToFinalResult(int[] finalResult, int[] tempResult, int position) {
        int remainder = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < tempResult.length; i++) {
            int currentValue = tempResult[i];
            int storedValue = finalResult[i + position];
            int sum = storedValue + currentValue + remainder;
            remainder = sum / 10;
            finalResult[i + position] = sum % 10;
        }
        finalResult[position + tempResult.length] = remainder;
    }
```

- And with numbers in normal order in array:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {1,2,3,6};
        int[] b = {8, 9, 1};

        System.out.println("Result is: " + Arrays.toString(calculate(a, b)));
    }

    private static int[] calculate(int[] a, int[] b) {
        // final result will be never longer than sum of number lengths + 1
        int[] finalResult = new int[a.length + b.length + 1];

        int positionFromEnd = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i <= a.length; i++) {
            int[] tempResult = multiplyWithOther(a[a.length-i], b);
            addToFinalResult(finalResult, tempResult, positionFromEnd);
            positionFromEnd++;
        }
        return finalResult;
    }

    private static int[] multiplyWithOther(int number, int[] otherArray) {
        // The number cannot be more digits than otherArray.length + 1, so create a temp array with size +1
        int[] temp = new int[otherArray.length + 1];
        // Iterate through the seconds array and multiply with current number from first
        int remainder = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i <= otherArray.length; i++) {
            int result = number * otherArray[otherArray.length - i];
            result += remainder;
            remainder = result / 10;
            temp[otherArray.length - i +1] = result % 10;
        }
        // Add remainder (even if 0) to start
        temp[0] = remainder;
        return temp;
    }

    private static void addToFinalResult(int[] finalResult, int[] tempResult, int positionFromEnd) {
        int remainder = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i <= tempResult.length; i++) {
            int currentValue = tempResult[tempResult.length - i];
            int storedValue = finalResult[finalResult.length - positionFromEnd - i];
            int sum = storedValue + currentValue + remainder;
            remainder = sum / 10;
            finalResult[finalResult.length - positionFromEnd - i] = sum % 10;
        }
        finalResult[finalResult.length - positionFromEnd - tempResult.length - 1] = remainder;
    }
```